# Sending a mail in PHP with Linux

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I have a program which works perfectly to send a mail in PHP using Windows, but now I want to send it using a cronjob in Linux to execute it everyday. What do I need to do to work in Linux? Do I need to configure the php.ini file, sendmail etc. like I did in Windows?

Here is the program I've used for sending the email.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); 
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$host = ".....";
$user = "....";
$pass = ".....";
$db = "......";




$con1 = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n");

$query1 = "select commands.author, users.badge_no
from commands
inner join users
on commands.author=users.username";

$rs1 = pg_query($con1, $query1) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");


$query = "SELECT distinct commands_details.delivery_date,commands_details.command_no,commands.author,commands_details.name
FROM commands_details
inner join commands
on commands_details.command_no=cast(commands.id as varchar)";

$rs = pg_query($con1, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

$nume=array();
$mail1=array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($rs1)){
    $nume[]=$row[0];  
    $mail1[]=$row[1];
}

$arrlength = count($nume);


$var_data='2016-06-19';
$mail_trimitere=array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($rs)) {
   if(strpos($row[0], $var_data) !== false){
        for($j=0;$j<$arrlength;$j++){
            if($row[2]===$nume[$j]){
                $mail_trimitere[0]=$mail1[$j];
                echo $mail_trimitere[0];
                break;
            }
        }

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


        $mail->Username = "......";
        $mail->Password = "........";

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
        $mail->SingleTo = true;

        $mail->From = "......";
        $mail->FromName = ".......";


        $mail->addAddress(".........","robert");

        $mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
        $mail->Body = 'urmeaza sa primiti maine comanda cu numarul '.' '.$row[1].' '.'produs'.' '. $row[3].' '. 'in data de '.' '.$row[0];

        if(!$mail->Send())
            echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        else
            echo "Message has been sent";


  }
}



pg_close($con1);


?>
```

Comment: Have you already got a mail server installed in your linux box?

Comment: Yy.... for mails right now you are using PhpMailer and you sent mails via gmail accout so you do not need anything else. THis should work also on LINUX

Comment: Nothing here suggests that this should work different from Windows. I'd check that your Linux set up is isn't throwing errors (maybe the `pg_` extension isn't installed?) by enabling error reporting. It would help if you clarified "doesn't work" for us. Does that mean you got the "Message was not sent ..."? or the script doesn't execute at all?

Comment: So basically I can use sendmail and run the same script as I did in Windows? In windows I used a cronjob.bat file containing the next program:

@echo off
cd C:\xampp\php
php C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\index.php

The index was my program.

HPierce, the script doesn't execute at all